# Question regarding function series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$ - continuity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$$
I know how to check if a series of functions is continuous.
The problem is, I need to check if series above is continuous in $(-\infty, \infty)$.
So I tried doing the $M$-test:
I did $$\frac{\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\right|}{\frac{|x|}{n^2}}\leq 1$$
for all $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$.
But: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{n^2}$$ is not convergent for $|x|\geq n$
But still, the answer says its convergent Uniformly... How so? if $x=n$ its a contradiction to it.
This is the most problematic question for me in calculus 2, I dont know why its uniformly continuity.

Comment: The $M$-test for absolute uniform convergence of series of functions fails for this series on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Medo Exactly, so how is it continuity? the answer says it is continuity.

Comment: I would try to calculate the partial sum explicitly using the fact $\sin{x}=\Im e^{ix}$, the imaginary part.

Comment: @Medo I dont really understand... If I found an x that it wont be uniformly convergence - why is it continuity? why is it related for M-Test?

Comment: @Medo Oh and I did not learn about that fact in calculus, in linear algebra we did, but barely.. only in linear algebra 1 ( first semester, so I dont really remember it sadly.. but anyway, my question is basically for all series, if I can find an x that will not be uniform convergence, why is it continuity till? )

Comment: Good question. Uniform convergence implies continuity. But a series that is not uniformly convergent may represent a continuous function. Take for example the Taylor expansion of the sine or cosine functions.

Comment: But the only sentence for continuity of series we learnt is this:
1. If the function series is uniform convergent. 
2. If the partial sums are continuity 
Thus, the series is continuity.
I dont know what you just said ,I never heard of it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say something like "$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{n^2}$ is not convergent for $|x|\geq n$". $n$ is a dummy variable, you can't talk about it aside from describing the summands. Actually $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{n^2} = |x|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges for all $x$.

Comment: @JairTaylor yea but there are some tests that I can input X=n and thus disproof the uniform continuity, it apperars mostly on functions of $fn(x)$ and less on series, but still it exists... also, the range is all X, so it should be able to be $x=n^3$ or even higher

Comment: @ Jair Taylor. Indeed (+1). It is not correct. I am taking it the partial sum from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: But you understand my problem? its not that exercise in particular, but in general, when I can input X such that it wont be uniformly convergence, I am having problem :\

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Continuity is a local property. This means that to check continuity it is enough to fix $x \in \Bbb R$, and see if the function is continuous at $x$.

Now, having fixed $x \in \Bbb R$, there is some integer $N$ big enough such that $$\frac{|x|}{N^2}<1$$
Hence the M-Test can be done using
$$M_n = \cases{1 & if $n <N$ \\ \frac{|x|}{n^2} & if $n \ge N$}$$
Since the series $\sum_n M_n$ is convergent, the M-Test applies, and in a neighbourhood of $x$ you have uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the proof, but its not the question itself that is problematic for me, but the understanding of it, the understand of why if I can input such an X that it will be not uniformly convergent, so it is still uniformly convergent.

Comment: @Crostul. Nice answer. Having fixed $x$, there exists $N>1$ such that $|x|/N<1$. No need for the square. It could confuse the reader. I would also emphasize that the sum $\sum M_n$ depends on $x$ (as it explicitly depends on $N$) but that is Ok locally.